# How can I set incremental or max value column of QueryCassandra Processor in Nifi?

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am using QueryCassandra processor in Nifi to fetch data from Cassandra to ingest MSSql table. But my Cassandra query is always running repetitive and I have not any option for setting of incremental or max value column in Cassandra Nifi's processor. How can I execute Nifi flow with incremental Cassandra query?

Comment: `incremental Cassandra query` ? What is that? Could you point the documentation about it?

Comment: I didn't see any incremental fetch processor in Nifi for cassandra.. so your option may be the scheduled snapshots from cassandra to mssql.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, it is still an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4105). If there is a JDBC driver for Cassandra, you may be able to use that with QueryDatabaseTable to do incremental fetching.